# Chrome browser is not opening on puppeteeer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am new to the puppeteer. Trying to access Chromium in a headless way but still facing the problem. The browser is not opening.

Please help me, anyone.

```
 const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    handless: false, 
    slowMo: 250
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://google.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean with "_The browser is not opening._"?

Comment: I mean when it executes it doesn't show the Chromium window. It is working well but the Chromium window is not opening. for that I have set this {handless: false}

Comment: You can check over here https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer